# Encryption scheme that requires fewer keys for decryption than for encryption

Tags: public-key

I want to attempt creating a decentralized dead man's switch, so I'm looking for an asymmetric encryption scheme, with the following properties (ideally), or something close to them:

1. There is a group of `n` people, each with their own public and private key.
2. Any one person can, at any time, encrypt a message using all public keys.
3. The catch that I'm looking for is that you wouldn't need all `n` private keys to decrypt the message, but only some number `k < n`.
4. It MUST be unfeasible to decrypt the message even if you have `k-1` keys, but very easy with `k` keys.
5. Once `k-1` receivers have comitted to the decryption, it MUST be impossible for the `k`th one to complete the decryption privately and obtain the message without publishing it. I intend to use it in an Ethereum contract, so there might be a way to avoid the impossibility of fair trade without a trusted party, using the blockchain.
6. (*optional*) The sender can choose the number `k` arbitrarily during encryption.
7. (*optional*) None of the receivers need to reveal their actual private keys during decryption.

Layered RSA (or any other asymmetric cipher for that matter), wouldn't do. It a) doesn't have property `5`, and b) requires encrypting your message in $\binom{n}{k}$ different ways, which is unfeasible for large numbers.

Does such a thing exist? Is it even theoretically possible?